# Atlassian Plugin Descriptor XML Schema

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm new in Jira Plugin development.

I would like to wrote **hello world plugin** [as described here](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started). For that purpose I used Atlassian SDK command `atlas-create-jira-plugin` which generates `atlassian-plugin.xml` configuration file without XML Schema. This way I'm unable to validate that file.

Is there anyway to provide schema manually for above xml descriptor file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [this](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/PLUG-1137) it looks like XSD or DTD is not available at the moment?

Comment: The help pages for [Configuring the plugin descriptor](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/configuring-the-plugin-descriptor) and [atlassian-plugin.xml Element Reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/configuring-the-plugin-descriptor/atlassian-plugin-xml-element-reference) don't mention any XSD or DTD either. If you try adding in a random element in the descriptor file, build the plugin, and upload, you will see some validation on the descriptor is done on the installation of the plugin, and the plugin will not be installed.